# Flashing mode in Android Flashlight app

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer, flashlight

As you can see I'm making flashlight for android which has 2 modes of flashing(first will make led flashing non-stop, second will make 0.5 second pause between flashes), but with my code it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
private void turnOnFlash() {
    if (!isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }

        params = camera.getParameters();

        switch(mode) {
            case 1:
                params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                break;
            case 2:
                timer = new CountDownTimer(1000, 500) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    }
                };
                break;
        }

        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashOn = true;

        playSound();
        toggleButtonImage();
    }
}
```

and here method in which mode is detected

```
tvMode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(mode) {
                case 1:
                    mode = 2;
                    tvMode.setText("2");
                    if(isFlashOn) {
                        turnOffFlash();
                        turnOnFlash();
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    mode = 1;
                    tvMode.setText("1");
                    if(isFlashOn) {
                        turnOffFlash();
                        turnOnFlash();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Well, It doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry. App will run and mode 1 works, but when I switch to mode 2 flash just turns off. I will edit question and post my code for detecting modes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. I forgot to put `.start();` on the end of CountDownTimer.